# Using R extract all rows that contain a string from a variable

Tags: r, matrix

I have a metadata file stored as a .tsv which I read into R and save as `META`. I need to extract all rows containing a given string "male", here stored in variable `sample`.

The full script has a lot of these operations and so it's important that I store the pattern in sample below. The errors are in the way I am trying to grep.

```
IN <- "/home/zchadva/Scratch/output/cov"

#metadata
META <- read.table("/home/zchadva/Scratch/data/hipsci/rnaseq/hipsci.qc1_sample_info.20160926.tsv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")

#Set study/table variables
sample <- "\\<male\\>"
control <- "female"

#Grep all rows containing "male" from the table META
sample.list <- META[grep(sample, META, value=TRUE)]
```

## EDIT: This has got me closer

Ideally I do not want to use `META$Gender` to specify a coloumn each time I need to do a pattern search as our real metadata file is humungous. If I do need to specify, I would like to have `Gender` in a variable

```
sample.list <- (META[grep(sample, META$Gender), ]
```

For example:

```
**coloumn** <- Gender
sample.list <- (META[grepl(sample, META$**coloumn**), ]

#Table example simplified
ID    Disease    Gender    Cell
JX1   ibd        male      liver
PTY   healthy    male      liver
HB3   ibd        female    brain
PO3   bbs        male      

#Desired layout in sample.list
JX1   ibd        male      liver
PTY   healthy    male      liver
PO3   bbs        male
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated. I have tried to do this for hours

Comment: so close!  Give `META[grepl(sample, META$Gender), ]` a try.

Comment: I tried this earlier but it returned only my first row (header). Each label on the header is separated however the output from this command spits it out as:

[1] name                               cell_type
 [3] derived_from                       donor
 [5] biosample_id                       tissue_biosample_id
 [7] donor_biosample_id                 derived_from_cell_type

Comment: Using the example above it would look like this: [1] ID [2] Disease [3] Gender [4] Cell

Comment: I had one flaw in my recommendation, but expanded and fixed the flaw as an answer.  with what you're describing, it sounds like you aren't using the comma between the `[ ]`.  Indexing a data frame requires `META[rows, cols]`.  If you use `META[index]`, you will only index the columns, not the rows.

Answer (score 1):

`grepl` will give you better results than `grep`, since you can use the logical vector to index your data frame.

```
META <- 
  data.frame(ID = c("JX1", "PTY", "HB3", "PO3"),
             Disease = c("ibd", "healthy", "ibd", "bbs"),
             Gender = c("male", "male", "female", "male"),
             Cell = c("liver", "liver", "brain", "liver"))

sample <- "male"
control <- "female"

META[grepl("^male", META$Gender), ]

   ID Disease Gender  Cell
1 JX1     ibd   male liver
2 PTY healthy   male liver
4 PO3     bbs   male liver
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Sorry I'm a total R noob, just want to check these things:

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, Sorry I'm a total R noob, just want to check these things:

-The metadata table is enormous, would I need to use the data.frame(ID...) snip you have there?

- META[grepl("^male", META$Gender), ] Just executed this in command  and it still only gave me my header row which doesn't contain "male"

- Ideally in "META[grepl("^male", META$Gender), ]" rather than writing male, I would like it to call on sample. I will run the script again with different variables such as disease, cell, etc and it's cleaner if I only need to change 1 bit of text